# Frameworks/Tools for managing big data workflows

Tags: workflow

Looking for a UI based (API is also welcome) workflow creation and management framework. I have found Azkaban from LinkedIn. Planning to evaluate few before choosing one.

Needs

- UI based workflow mgmt
- auth and authorization based on LDAP
- audit log of all actions
- support for Spark, hadoop/clouded/Cassandra/scripts
- dependency management

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/project.html) is a workflow management tool.

Workflows are defined as DAGs using a Python based DSL.

It's more generic than [Azkaban](https://azkaban.github.io/), providing operators for several tools (python, bash, SQL, Docker amongst others).

No integration with LDAP so far.